# Error 'Can't exec "aclocal"' with homebrew installed autoreconf on mac

Tags: homebrew, autoreconf

When running `autoreconf -fi` after having done `brew install autoreconf` on my ARM mac, I get the following error:

```
$ autoreconf -fi                     
Can't exec "aclocal": No such file or directory at /opt/homebrew/Cellar/autoconf/2.71/share/autoconf/Autom4te/FileUtils.pm line 274.
autoreconf: error: aclocal failed with exit status: 2
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sort of a duplicate of this superuser question (linking to answer): https://superuser.com/a/897316/1056672

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `aclocal` wasn't installed together with `autoreconf`, see e.g. this [homebrew issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/21125).

It's easy to solve by brew installing `aclocal` separately:

```
brew install automake
```